# convert images into zip folder in phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am using phonegap to take picture and upload it to the server in android phone. Now before uploading to the server i want to convert all the images to the zip. Is it possible in phonegap or do i have any other solution???

```
function zipBlob(filename, blob, callback) {
    alert("inside zipBlob");
   // use a zip.BlobWriter object to write zipped data into a Blob object
   zip.createWriter(new zip.BlobWriter("application/zip"), function(zipWriter) {
      // use a BlobReader object to read the data stored into blob variable
      zipWriter.add(filename, new zip.BlobReader(blob), function() {
         // close the writer and calls callback function
         zipWriter.close(callback);
      });
   }, onerror);

}
```

I tried this but that is giving blob error.
Any help?? 
through zip.js it is possible to zip the images in normal browsers but not in mobile browser.